# Is the Stack Overflow App available on iPhone?

Tags: app, stackapps, iphone

There used to be an App of Stack Overflow on iPhone. But I don't find it in the App Store anymore.

Is it removed from the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The mobile apps are unfortunately discontinued.

You can read the formal post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076), quoting the most relevant part:

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Related [If development on the Stack Exchange iOS/Android apps has ceased indefinitely, what should we do to their bug reports and feature requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324550)

Comment: What is going on with the app? Why is it discontinued? Given many websites have accompanying apps, it is counterintuitive that SO went in the opposite direction. This seems to be quite a bad sign for the company.

Comment: @user15482691 they are sold for 1.8B and I wouldn't call that a bad sign. SE inc. has a strong focus on making money with a small team. The Apps didn't have a revenue stream with only marginal use. While a loss for the thousands of users that relied on the app, from a business perspective it is an understandable decision to abandon development of mobile apps. That doesn't mean I like it or am happy with that but in the grand scheme of things it is a move I can live with, assuming this will keep them in business and have the small dev team focus on other features that benefit more users.

Comment: Do you have the news article describing the sale? I don't know that that app is worth 1.8B. How is the current revenue of SE? Is the management under severe pressure to make the company profitable?

Comment: @user15482691 here you go: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/ and yes, SE is a for profit company and that often means that things that cost money to make and maintain but don't generate revenue will be terminated sooner or later. SE is not the size of Google, Github, Twitter, Facebook so they have to make difficult decisions everyday to keep the company afloat for the years ahead. In this case that means cutting back on products they wish to support.